# Multiple Inheritance in python with super()

Tags: python, inheritance

My code:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, a = 100):
        self.a = a

class B():
    def __init__(self, b = 200):
        self.b = b

class C(A,B):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c = 300):
        super().__init__(a)
        super().__init__(b)
        self.c = c

    def output(self):
        print(self.a)
        print(self.b)
        print(self.c)


def main():
    c = C(1,2,3)`enter code here`
    c.output()

main()
```

Error:

```
2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "inheritance.py", line 25, in <module>
    main()
  File "inheritance.py", line 23, in main
    c.output()
  File "inheritance.py", line 17, in output
    print(self.b)
AttributeError: 'C' object has no attribute 'b'
```

Why it cannot inheritance the b?
what's wrong with this code???
And how to modify this code?

If I replace the supper() with A. or B. , it can run normally.
So what cause this problem?
If I do not use super(), what method can I use?

Comment: `super().__init__` gives you the constructor of the class `A`. That means you're initializing your `C` instance with the constructor of `A` twice, and never call the constructor of `B`.

Answer (score 0):

Inherit from object + fixed your "super" call

```
class A(object):
   def __init__(self, a = 100):
      self.a = a

class B(object):
   def __init__(self, b = 200):
      self.b = b

class C(A,B):
   def __init__(self, a, b, c = 300):
      A.__init__(self, a=a)
      B.__init__(self, b=b)
      self.c = c

   def output(self):
      print(self.a)
      print(self.b)
      print(self.c)
```